# For loop not running in Java

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have declared the Map of java.util.Map class. And i have declared For loop to get the key-value pairs but the loop is not running.My codes is:

```
public class ContactService {

    public void getAll(){
         System.out.println("here");
        Department d1=new Department(1,"A","floor");
        Department d2=new Department(2,"B","gigh floor");

        Employee e1=new Employee(1,"ashiwin");
        Employee e2=new Employee(2,"anil");
        Employee e3=new Employee(3,"suman");
        Employee e4=new Employee(4,"ronak");
        Employee e5=new Employee(5,"Bidhya");

        LRUCache<Employee,Department> cache=LRUCache.newInstance(3);

        cache.put(e1, d1);
        cache.put(e2, d2);
        cache.put(e3, d1);

        cache.put(e4, d2);
        cache.put(e5, d1);

        Set<Map.Entry<Employee,Department>> entrySet=cache.entrySet();
         System.out.println("hereaaa");
        for(Map.Entry<Employee,Department> entry:entrySet){
             Employee emp=entry.getKey();

              Department dept=entry.getValue();

              System.out.println(emp);
              System.out.println(dept);
       }


    }
}
```

I am calling this method from:

```
package com.ashwin.jaxmaven11;


import com.ashwin.jaxmaven11.cache.Department;
import com.ashwin.jaxmaven11.cache.Employee;
import com.ashwin.jaxmaven11.cache.LRUCache;
import com.ashwin.jaxmaven11.service.ContactService;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path(value="contact")
public class ContactAPI {

    @GET
    public String index(){

       ContactService cs=new ContactService();
       cs.getAll();

        return "hello";
    }

}
```

I am not using spring or any other java frameworks.I wanted to look inside the  `for(Map.Entry<Employee,Department> entry:entrySet){}` loop but while trying to print sout inside the for loop is not printed in console.
The output printed is upto the upper block of for loop.The output printed is:

[image]

LRUCache.java

```
package com.ashwin.jaxmaven11.cache;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author AshwinPC
 */
public class LRUCache<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V>  {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 3801124242820219131L;
     private int size;

     private LRUCache(int size){
         super(size,0.75f,true);
     }

     @Override
     protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
        return size()>size;
    }

     public static<K, V> LRUCache<K,V> newInstance(int size){
         return new LRUCache<K,V>(size);
     }

    public LRUCache() {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in your `removeEldestEntry` method, you've never actually set your `size` variable in `LRUCache` therefore it's 0.

`removeEldestEntry` is called after `put` or `putAll` ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry))), when you put something for the first time the value of `size()` in `removeEldestEntry` is 1, which is larger than `size` which is 0.

Therefore the eldest item will be removed, which is the item you've just added.

**Solution:**
Add `this.size = size` in the constructor of `LRUCache` and it will work.

Comment: in default or parameterized constructor?

Comment: In `LRUCache(int size)`

Comment: @AshwinKarki There is no default constructor since you declared a constructor. You only get a *default* constructor when no constructors are declared.